# Using JavaScript to change local src of an HTML iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Lets say you have a main .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page One</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javaS.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
</head>
<body id="main">
<h3>Test switching html content inside iframe</h3>
<p>iframe:</p>
<iframe src="" id="iframe1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And a secondary .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page two</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
</head>
<body id="test">
<h3>Test subject</h3>
<p>subjugate text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How would you display the **local** second .html inside the iframe element of the first .html, using only JavaScript?

I have tried using these snippets:

```
window.onload = function() {window.frames['iframe1'].location.replace("Secondary.html");}
```

.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
iframe.src = "second.html";
```

...But these haven't worked. I'm new at this so the answer might be fairly obvious, but any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this and it works well:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('iframe1').src = "Secondary.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("src", "http://your-url.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet is perfect. You just have to make sure that it runs when iframe DOM element exists - in `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

I just combined the two exampples you had tried to make one working example, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/4p18mxg9/9/

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
window.onload = function() {
    iframe.src = "second.html";
}
```